# How do I compare values across two different .csv files?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have two .csv files, one is a dump from a third party application the other is a dump from Active Directory (using PowerShell).

The third party .csv looks something like this

| e-mail address | Name | Title | Dept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john@work.com | John | Engineer | Office |
| mary@work.com | Mary | Supervisor | Factory |

The AD .csv looks something like this

| e-mail address | Name | Title | Dept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john@work.com | John | Engineer | Main Office |
| mary@work.com | Mary | Team Supervisor | Factory |

Is there a way (ideally in PowerShell) that the two .csv files can be read and the differences highlighted and exported to third file.

e.g for the row containing john@work.con the Dept value is different, for the row containing mary@work.com the Title is different

The output would look something like this - where "Please update" has been entered into the required cell.

| e-mail address | Name | Title | Dept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john@work.com | John | Engineer | **Please update** |
| mary@work.com | Mary | **Please update** | Factory |

Regards
Philip

Comment: You can use `Compare-Object` to compare the differences between both CSVs. What is your expected output after the comparison ?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I forgot about describing the output, I have updated my OP.

Comment: Can we assume that both CSVs will always have the same properties (the same columns) ? And also, what is the reference column used for Comparison ? I would assume both CSVs are compared based on the `e-mail address` Column, is that so ?

Comment: Yes, they will always have the same columns and the e-mail address will be the reference column.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can do it, using `Group-Object`, using these CSVs as example:

```
$csv1 = @'
e-mail address,Name,Title,Dept
john@work.com,John,Engineer,Office
mary@work.com,Mary,Supervisor,Factory
guy@work.com,Guy,Supervisor,Factory
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$csv2 = @'
e-mail address,Name,Title,Dept
john@work.com,John,Engineer,Main Office
mary@work.com,Mary,Team Supervisor,Factory
otherguy@work.com,Other Guy,Team Supervisor,Factory
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Group both objects by their `e-mail address` property and then if the group count is **equal to 1**, skip that object since there is nothing to compare, else, compare each property against each other and update the property value of one of the objects (the object with index `0` in this case, which will be the one we return):

```
$csv1 + $csv2 | Group-Object 'e-mail address' | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.Count -eq 1) { return }
    # following assumes there will be no more than 2 elements!
    # it also assumes both CSVs have the same column names!
    foreach($prop in $_.Group[0].PSObject.Properties.Name) {
        if($_.Group[0].$prop -ne $_.Group[1].$prop) {
            $_.Group[0].$prop = 'Please Update'
        }
    }
    $_.Group[0]
} | Format-Table
```

The result we can expect from above example, as you can see, **guy** and **otherguy** are not taken into consideration for the comparison:

```
e-mail address Name Title         Dept
-------------- ---- -----         ----
john@work.com  John Engineer      Please Update
mary@work.com  Mary Please Update Factory
```